# Creating a pointer to the State of a File and reading in

Tags: c++, file, pointers

I have some old code to adapt to which uses some sort of resource address system to load a file (fpgaDevice). It uses these FindResource and load, lock resource mehtods to get a pointer to the start of the file, as well as the size of the file. Then just reads word by word.

```
ULONG nAvailableWords = 0;
  ULONG nFileLength = 0;
  ULONG nCurrentPoint = 0;
  HRSRC res;
  HGLOBAL resHandle = NULL;
  char* resData;
     res = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(fpgaDevice), L"FPGADATA");
      resHandle = LoadResource(NULL, res);
      resData = (char*)LockResource(resHandle);
      // Get the file length
      nFileLength = SizeofResource(NULL, res);
```

Instead I am trying to adapt to the same sort of system, only with a string that has a corresponding address path to the file.
ie:

```
std::string PATH = "C:\\PathToFile\\file.bin";
```

Is there a way to pull off this same sort of system, get a pointer to the top of the bin file, and the size.. and be able to read word by word. There is some other code that I need to be compatible with, which is why I am kinda forced to do it this way..

Later on I retrieve data by using:

```
(ULONG*)resData
```

and advance the pointer by

```
resData += sizeof(ULONG)
```

Comment: What you seem to want to do is general file reading, which is a very basic subject in just about all languages.

Comment: Yeah, basic file I/O. ifstream to open the file, fstat for the file size. And see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: yeah i got that.. I was more unsure about how I would set that to a char pointer so I could be compatible with the same code.. if that makes sense

Comment: You don't need to do much really. Just allocate enough memory in a suitable container (I suggest you start to use e.g. `std::vector<int8_t>` instead), fill it with the contents from the file, and use it as before.

Comment: Background: for pointer arithmetic as intended to do, you need contiguous memory containing the data. This is why you need to read in all the file into memory before you can go on.

Comment: does anyone have an example of this.. really lost..